# Running an Access .accdb as a different user

Tags: microsoft-access

I have an Access program that uses SQL server tables and I want it to run as a different user than the logged on user.  How would I do this?

Comment: What is your environment (one or two computers etc.)?

Comment: You what to run ms-access as other user, or connect to sql-server as other user? What connection do you use in ms-access.

Comment: I am running this application on the desktop.  It uses windows logon credentials to determine if the user has access to the linked SQL server tables.

Comment: So you want to run ms-access as different user to authenticate as other user at sql-server, but don't login on windows as this user? You tried right-click while holding shift on msaccess.exe (not database) and select`Run as different User`or create a shell script to start the db and use shift+ right-click on that? Reason for your needs?